# Pressure in the turbopump

Tags: turbopump

Which pressure is considered, when using the head calculation (stagnation or static)?
Are these pressures absolute or gauge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these question may have different answers based on who you ask, so it is important to make sure you know what an author is talking about.

That being said, usually, stagnation pressure is used and all pressures are given as absolute.